Example of abelian quotient $A/B\cong\mathbb{Q}$ that doesn't split?
Can someone show me an example of an abelian group $A$ and its subgroup $B$ such that $A/B\cong Q\leq\mathbb{Q}$ so that the short exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow A/B\longrightarrow0$$
doesn't split? For what choices of $Q$ does there exist such example? If $Q\cong\mathbb{Z}$ then there are no such examples, but does every other choice of $Q$ have an example?
I am sure that such an example exists (for at least some $Q$) because if it didn't then I could use transfinite induction to prove that this sequence splits whenever $A/B$ is torsion-free, but there are example contradicting this.

You are asking which subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ are projective $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Clearly, $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are projective, and every subgroup isomorphic to these (as abstract groups). Every finitely generated subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic (and torsionfree) and hence projective. But $\mathbb{Q}$ itself is not projective, hence provides a counterexample. Specifically, the canonical epimorphism from the free abelian group $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{Q}$ does not split (for example, since a free abelian group has no non-trivial divisible abelian subgroup), and with its kernel $B$ then $0 \to B \to \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{Q} \to 0$ does not split.

Thank you! Can you please elaborate on what $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{Q}}$ actually is? I am sorry I can't understand the solution because I don't know this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum resp. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group

Yes but what is the direct sum when the symbol for the sum is in the exponent? I understand this is some free abelian group, but I don't understand which and I don't understand the canonical epimorphism. I'm sorry.

$A^{\oplus I} = \bigoplus_{i \in I} A$ (which I am sure you can find by reading the linked articles)

Oh! I get it now! Ok, this is a beautiful construction, thank you once again :)
